# Using Gaussian function in the proof of Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to understand the details of one version of the proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem. In order to prove it, we use a lemma that states that if our function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous  and has a compact support, then $$|f_\sigma - f|\xrightarrow[\sigma\to 0]{} 0,$$ where 
$$f_\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt.$$

To prove that, we use a property of the Gaussian function $$K(s, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-s^2}{2\sigma^2}}:$$

\begin{align*}
\int_{|s|\geq\delta} K(s, \sigma) ds 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{|s|\geq\delta} e^{\frac{-s^2}{2\sigma^2}} ds\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{|s|\geq\delta} e^{\frac{-\delta s}{2\sigma^2}} ds\\
&\leq \frac{4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sigma}{\delta} e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\xrightarrow[\sigma\to 0]{} 0
\end{align*}

It is the last two inequalities that I don't understand. Why do we have the right to substitute one of the $s$ for $\delta$ and why can't we substitute the other one?

Comment: If we substitute the other one for a $\delta$, then the integral diverges.

Comment: Ok, so I see why we substitute one "s" for delta. Can you advise me on how do we take the integral? Initially I thought that "s" is a complex number, but now I have some doubts. If it is real, we can split the integral in two: (-\infty, -delta], [delta, \infty) and then just calculate it as usual?

Comment: Yeah, $s$ is real and you can calculate the integral "as usual". So, basically, the calculation boils down to an integral of the form $$\int_a^{\infty} e^{-bs} \, ds$$ for some constant $a,b>0$.

Comment: It seems that we are making a mistake when replacing the s by delta for the first time: depending on the part of the integral, we should put either delta, or -delta. So, if we split the integral first, then we can replace s with +/- delta in the corresponding integrals. Does it make sense?

Comment: BTW, you kinda answered my question, so if you put it all together in the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, we could do so. Note, however, that we can write $$\exp \left( - \frac{s^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) = \exp \left(- \frac{|s|^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$$ and then we can use $|s| \geq \delta$. (So there is no mistake in the calculation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If we substitue the other $s$ for a $\delta$, then the integral diverges.
2. The integral is a "standard" (improper) Riemann integral, i.e. we can calculate it as usual. Splitting the integral $$\int_{|s| \geq \delta} = \int_{(-\infty,-\delta]} + \int_{[\delta,\infty)}$$ the calculation boils down to integrals of the form $$\int_{[a,\infty)} e^{-bs} \, ds$$ for some constants $a,b>0$.